# Refused to connect to 'https://lnkd.demdex.net/event?_ts=1582621446900' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

I am using Oauth2.0 for LinkedIn social login in my React.js project but on LinkedIn login page I am facing this warning:

> Refused to connect to 'https://lnkd.demdex.net/event?_ts=1582621446900' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https://media-src.linkedin.com/media/ wss://www.linkedin.com s.c.lnkd.licdn.com m.c.lnkd.licdn.com static.licdn.com static-exp1.licdn.com static-exp2.licdn.com static-exp3.licdn.com media.licdn.com media-exp1.licdn.com media-exp2.licdn.com media-exp3.licdn.com"."